# Pushing from One View to Another via UIButton (UINavigationController)

Tags: iphone, sdk

I've tried every solution on Google and nothing seems to work. So far I've implemented a UINavigationController with the App Delegate, now all I want to accomplish is changing to the *WebViewController* by clicking the UIButton I've created in the interface builder, but the button doesn't seem to do anything when I run the application. Keep in mind that I want it to *push* to my *WebViewController* view.

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];  
    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)createFile:(id)sender {
    WebViewController *webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:NSBundle.mainBundle];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];
}
```

**Note:** In the interface builder I've already connected *createFile* to the button.

I understand that this is usually something that comes known as super easy but for some reason I've just never gotten it to work. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I added the retaining property, sythesized it and added to my code in the ViewController.m file:

```
WebViewController *webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:NSBundle.mainBundle];
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:webViewController];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];
```

But now the app crashes on the button click and returns with a SIGABRT: "*Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported (WebViewController: 0x1ed70e80)*"

Comment: now you are pushing the same view on the same navigation stack twice.  your init method uses the webViewController as the rootViewController and then you try to push the exact same webViewController on again.

Comment: also when assigning the root view Controller you should use self.window.rootViewController = navigationController instead of [self.window addSubView:navigationController.view]

Comment: Okay well I replaced the [self.window addSubView:navigationController.view] with "self.window.rootViewController = navigationController" and I took out the initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:NSBundle.mainBundle], but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: WebViewController *webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:NSBundle.mainBundle];
  followed by  [self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];

Comment: you are assigning self.navigationController from within the viewController and then the viewController can't operate because you are reassigning its own navigation Controller

Comment: Okay I just tried this, but the button still doesn't work. Like it's not going to the WebViewController after click.

Comment: Thanks a ton for help btw. Means a lot!

Comment: no prob, just to double check. In interface builder you have the proper outlet set.  file owner is set to your ViewController class.  and the outlet from the buttons is set to your ViewControllers IBAction named createFile.

Comment: Yes sir. @MDT response below works and changes to the new view so I know every things setup right, but the problem with his code is that it doesn't tie in the UINavigationController (no top bar on new view).

Comment: if you want a new navigation controller /navigation bar with a modal style view you'll have to allocate a new one and then assign your view controller to it. so init WebView, Init UINavigationController with webView as root. then presentModalViewController:naivgationController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give this a try

```
-(IBAction)createFile:(id)sender{
    WebViewController *webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc]
     initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:nil];
    webViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:webViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Great :) got this to work but it also gets rid of the UINavigationController (top bar disappears) which I was looking to keep. I was looking for a push styled view change as well, but I'm guessing you can easily change that with _UIModalTransitionStylePush_

Comment: alright then take a look at this, it should help clear this up
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleDrillDown/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007416

Answer (score -1):

One thing i noticed is that you are not retaining your navigationController in the appDelegate.  So what may be happening is that your the navigationControllers view may be present and retained (from the all to addSubView) but the navigation controller may have been deallocated.

in your AppDelegate try making the Navigation Controller a retaining property

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UINavigationController *navigationController
```

in your .m file

```
@synthesize navigationController
```

and then

Edit: Updated for pushing a view controller

```
WebViewController *webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:NSBundle.mainBundle];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: You can't be serious. UIViewController has a retained property called navigationController. Also, if it was deallocated, app would crash.

Comment: @fichek: The window is only holding onto the UINavigationController's view, so the former will be deallocated immediately.  richerd's answer is addressing a legitimate problem.

Comment: I did tried it out,  and @fichek is right that UINavigationController is a retained property of UIViewController, and my test app appeared to work properly.  But still the UINavigationController should be the one directing the UIViewController and not the other way around.

Comment: @titaniumdecoy initializing UINavigationController with an instance of UIViewController sets that view controller's `.navigationController`, which is a retained property. So as long as that view controller exists, navigation controller will exists too unless you over-release it. So please don't upvote incorrect answers or try to argue with me without a single argument.